# How to replace or convert the first occurrence of a dot from a string in java

Tags: java, string

Example: 
Input

```
Str = P.O.Box
```

Output

```
Str= PO BOX
```

I can able to convert the string to uppercase and replace all dot(.) with a space.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s = "P.O.Box 1836";
    String uppercase = s.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("uppercase "+uppercase);
    String replace = uppercase.replace("."," ");
    System.out.println("replace "+replace);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.print(s.toUpperCase().replaceFirst("[.]", "").replaceAll("[.]"," "));`

Comment: the first dot need to be removed

Comment: Your output will be EMPTY. Please check why.

Comment: @jayamohan i forgot the []     :)

Comment: @pawan You should escape the dot with a `\`

Answer (score 0):

If you look the String API carefully, you would notice that there's a methods that goes by:-

```
replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `replaceFirst` method twice. First for replacing the `.` with  `<nothing>`. Second for replacing the second `.` with a  `<space>`.

```
String str = "P.O.Box";
str = str.replaceFirst("[.]", "");
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("[.]", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

This one liner should do the job:

```
String s = "P.O.Box";
String replace = s.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\.(?=[^.]*\\.)", "").replace('.', ' ');
//=> PO BOX
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String resultValue = "";
        String[] result = uppercase.split("[.]");


        for (String value : result)
        {
           if (value.toCharArray().length > 1)
            {
                resultValue = resultValue + " " + value;
            }
            else
            {
                resultValue = resultValue + value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("P.O.Box".toUpperCase().replaceFirst("\\.","").replaceAll("\\."," "));
```

Out put

```
PO BOX
```

NOTE: `\\` is needed here if you just use `.` only your out put will blank.

Live [demo](http://ideone.com/KuObtk).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `replaceFirst` method twice.

```
String replace = uppercase.replace("\\.", "").replaceFirst("\\.", "");
```

Comment: This is not `replaceFirst`, but `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score -3):

As you want to remove the first dot and replace the second one with a space, you need replace the whole P.O. section

Use

```
replace("P\\.O\\.", "PO ");
```

Comment: But he *does* want to replace with a space.

Comment: The `String.replace()` takes two chars as arguments.

Comment: @kocko there is also a replace() that takes 2 charsequences ;)